# Having difficulties Uploading Photo in Database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload, photo

Need Help:
I am using a simple PHP code to upload photos into remote database. But.. Everytime, two copies of one photo is saved int the DB.
Can anyone tell me whats I am doing wrong?
PHP Code:

```
<?PHP
$uploadDir = 'image_folder/'; 



$uploadDir = 'image_folder/'; 

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))  //info saving in the variables
{
$fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath); //moving the photo in the         destination
if (!$result) {
echo "Error uploading file";
exit;
}
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
echo "".$filePath."";
$query = "INSERT INTO picture (image) VALUES ('$filePath')";
if (mysql_query($query))
{echo "Inserted";}
mysql_query($query) or die('Error loading file!'); 
}?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (mysql_query($query))
{echo "Inserted";}
mysql_query($query) or die('Error loading file!');
```

you are calling `mysql_query($query)` twice

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `mysql_query($query)` two times, first in `IF{}` and right after it. :D

ps. `mysql_*` functions are depricated, use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_query` two times. Try this:

```
if (mysql_query($query)) {
  echo "Inserted";
} else {
 die('Error loading file!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing mysql_query twice. Modify your if to:

```
  if (mysql_query($query)) {
        echo "Inserted";
  } else {
     die('Error loading file!')
  }
```

And, remove the following line:

```
 mysql_query($query) or die('Error loading file!');
```

Note: Make sure that you read the warning box in https://www.php.net/mysql_query. mysql_* functions are deprecated.